# Add Values From Associative Array If Keys Match

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I am attempting to add values from an associative array when the keys match. The end goal would be the ability to achieve an output like this:

`Total Ups: 219`
`Aug. 1 Ups: 105`
`Aug. 2 Ups: 52`
`Aug. 3 Ups: 62`

I have got the following that **works** for the lump sum of array values:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  foreach ($value['report']['daily']['ups'] as $rec){
    $upsArr[] = $rec;
  }
}

echo array_sum($upsArr);
```

However, when I attempt to calculate the sum for a single date, say Aug. 1, I cannot seem to walk through to the second level of keys with any success. I have the following to see if could get to the needed level:

```
foreach($array as $key => $subArr){
  foreach($subArr as $id => $value['report']['daily']['ups'][1]){
    print_r($value);
  }
}
```

Here is the array I am working with:

```
$array = array(
  array(
    store  => 'South',
    report => array(
      daily  => array(
        ups => array('Aug. 1' => '19', 'Aug. 2' => '11', 'Aug. 3' => '13'),
        sold => array('Aug. 1' => '11', 'Aug. 2' => '5', 'Aug. 3' => '5')
    )),
  ),
  array(
    store  => 'East',
    report => array(
      daily  => array(
        ups => array('Aug. 1' => '38', 'Aug. 2' => '22', 'Aug. 3' => '23'),
        sold => array('Aug. 1' => '16', 'Aug. 2' => '8', 'Aug. 3' => '8')
    )),
  ),
  array(
    store  => 'West',
    report => array(
      daily  => array(
        ups => array('Aug. 1' => '48', 'Aug. 2' => '19', 'Aug. 3' => '26'),
        sold => array('Aug. 1' => '28', 'Aug. 2' => '4', 'Aug. 3' => '11')
    )),
  )
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the "associative array"? Where is the expected result?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I gave them a read and improved the question and formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check this out**

```
$detail = [];
foreach ($array as $item){
    foreach ($item['report']['daily']['ups'] as $date=>$total){
        if (!array_key_exists($date, $detail)){
            $detail[$date] = $total;
        }else{
            $detail[$date] += $total;
        }
    }
}
// int 219
var_dump(array_sum($detail));

var_dump($detail);
/*
array (size=3)
'Aug. 1' => int 105
'Aug. 2' => int 52
'Aug. 3' => int 62
*/
```

Comment: Thank you -- it all makes sense now as I was not looping through the array before attempting to loop through the sub array.